# how to apply the same transformation to all files in a folder

Tags: r

I am new to R I have 1200 gene expression files with only two columns gene name and gene expression value I am looking to filter out 63 of these genes and generate a gene file with only the gene expression values for these genes so can eventually but these values 63 values for each 1200 samples all together in a single database

I have a index file with the ids and row number of the genes I would like to extract essentially:

```
row . Gene . Id 
132 . ESM1 . ENSG00000164283
689 . RASS . ENSG00000066697
...   ....   ...............
...   ....   ...............
```

and so on down to 63.  The gene expression files are just two columns with the gene Id and a gene expression value, along 63000 rows so something like this:

```
ENSG00000164283 . 3234.345
ENSG00000066697 . 255.346
ENSG00000046895 . 4587.322
...............   ........
...............   ........
```

and so on.  I can extract these lines into a new variable by subsetting the gene expression file by with the index file

```
index.table<-read.table("path to file")
index<-index.table[,1]

sample.1<-read.table("path to file")
S1<-sample.1[index,2]

sample.2<-read.table("path to file")
S2<-sample.2[index,2]

sample.3<-read.table("path to file")
S3<-sample.3[index,2]
```

will give me the subsets that I need, which I can then bind the columns into a single file for all gene expression values for all samples

```
gene.DB<-cbind(S1,S2,S3,S4.....S1200)
```

however this is very impractical to do for 1200 individual files how can I loop this function to run on all files in this given directory? I apologize if this is a very basic question but I just can seem to know how to do it, Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Andres

Comment: Something like `l <- list.files('my_folder/'); purrr::map_dfc(l, ~read.table(.)[index, 2])`

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `sapply` to build a matrix of gene expression values after building a named list of files (assuming all 1,200 reside in same directory):

```
index_table <- read.table("path to file")
index <- index_table[,1]

gene_files <- list.files("path to all gene file")
names(gene_files) <- paste0("S", seq_along(gene_files))

samples <- sapply(gene_files, function(f) read.table(f)[index,2])
```